# default custome webpart became static on custom site page

Tags: 2010, web-part, sharepoint-enterprise

I have created a custom site page in sharepoint 2010 and added the following code to it

```
<WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" FrameType="TitleBarOnly" ID="Main" Title="loc:Main" >
 <ZoneTemplate>                       
   <WpNs0:DashBoard runat="server" ID="g_55249317_828e_4af6_a7bc_94bff9a8468b"    
                 Description="TicketTale DashBoard WebPart"
                 Title="TicketTale DashBoard WebPart"             
                 __MarkupType="vsattributemarkup" 
                 __WebPartId="{55249317-828E-4AF6-A7BC-94BFF9A8468B}"
                 WebPart="true" __designer:IsClosed="false" partorder="2">
   </WpNs0:DashBoard>
 </ZoneTemplate>
</WebPartPages:WebPartZone>
```

and i have created a custom webpart which is included in the webpartzone above the webpart is working fine but the problem is the webpart became static meaning that i can't modify or delete it, although when i add it manually to the same page or any other page ,i can modify or delete it normally,

help please!!!

Answer (score 1):

When you add a webpart like this it is by design you cannot edit it, you are turning it from a webpart into a control.

If you want to add it programatically the only way is through powershell/event handler or form/console application.